# Windows 10 Threshold 2 Update Failed - BSOD: MEMORY_MANAGEMENT

Tags: memory, windows-10, motherboard, bsod, windows-10-v1511

Let me detail what happened in order:

Yesterday I checked for Windows updates and found that Threshold 2/1511 was out. I attempted to install.

Mid installation I got a Blue Screen stating the error "MEMORY_MANAGEMENT". Windows restored my previous version and I tried searching online for a possible solution.

I came across a few sources saying that it could be a motherboard BIOS issue and that it may need updated, I updated from v802 to 1102 using Asus' built int EzFlash via. a USB stick. The computer then rebooted to a black screen, no mobo beep.

I read some manuals and seen there was a MemOK button which attempts to configure the RAM timings automatically, I managed to get it to boot.

To test this again I went back into the BIOS and set memory settings to "AUTO", again black screen, no beep but power on. MemOK seems to find the correct timings to allow me to boot and run Windows 10 pre-threshold 2 update.

I tried running System File Checker from command line (sfc /scannow) and it scanned, stated it had found and resolved some errors.

I then tried running Windows Memory Diagnostics Tool which rebooted into the program, scanned and rebooted. Before the reboot the detected errors list was empty, but no dialog popped up when I logged in.

A further attempt at installing the update again resulted in the same BSoD as before.

Searching the web would appear to suggest running CPU-Z and checking the SPD section and making sure the timings table matches the RAM specifications but I am not quite sure what to do with it.

If anyone has had a similar issue or knows how to read this table then the help would be greatly appreciated.

I will have to wait until after work to try any suggestions but I will keep this post updated as things progress - if at all.

Complete computer specs are as follows:

- Motherboard: ASUS Maximus VIII HERO
- CPU: i7-6700k
- Cooler: Corsair H80i
- RAM: 32GB Hyper-X Fury DDR4 2666MHz (4x8gb)
- GPU: Geforce 980Ti (Palit)
- PSU: Corsair CS650M
- HDDs: Primary - 1TB Samsung 850 EVO SSD, Secondary - 2TB Seagate SSHD
  (8GB SSD Cache)

Thanks for your time.

**EDIT**

Here is a screenshot of the Memory and SPD tabs in CPU-Z, apologies for the delay.

[image]

Also the minidump info can be found here:

[Minidump Analysis](http://pastebin.com/BPyuizPu)

Finally, here's some more detailed information using BlueScreenView for the above dump:

[image]

**UPDATE**

It was indeed **Asus AI Suite 3** that was causing the issue. Uninstalling this entire suite and also clearing the ProgramData folder containing the setup, etc, allowed me to install the update first time.

Thanks again guys for the feedback and keeping me reassured that there was a fix. I appreciate it.

Comment: Without the .dmp file for the BSOD we can't really help with the BSOD.  I am honestly confused on what problem you want help with.

Comment: in all probability from what i see on the web is it is about drivers and filters (in drivers) and not about your ram failing, although it wouldnt hurt to set your ram down and stop any crasy overclocking while testing.  So indeed knowing what the error points to would be very important.

Comment: @Ramhound My apologies, I shall look out the log file when I can. I was asking about either: information on how to use CPU-z in order to read the correct settings for manually changing the ram config in the bios or if there is any other possible causes. My plans are to try tweak the settings and perhaps scan the ram using memtest86 to see if that finds a fault. Failing that I feel I may have a dud stick and try the update with one in instead of all four.

Comment: You don't post a screenshot of CPU-Z so we can't tell you what XMP profiles it detects.

Comment: Added more information, sorry for being too eager to post before I had the time to collect it.

Comment: "I tried running System File Checker from command line (sfc /scannow) and it scanned, stated it had found and resolved some errors." - Please supply us with the log file.  Have you also ran the DISM tool and SFC (again) to verify your system, now its been repaired, has zero problems?  CPU-Z indicates which JEDEC profiles you should be using.

Comment: @Ramhound Filtered SFC Details from CBS.log: [SFC Results](http://pastebin.com/YDn4P84Y) - I shall try running it again, DISM tool's check health command would appear to tell me that no corruptions are detected. Perhaps it's just a driver issue with the update and my specific hardware combination?

Comment: @Jayse - Its possible its a driver problem.  It should be easy enough to determine what driver is causing the problem though.

Comment: After some Googling it would appear the file running when the crash happened, "aaHMSvc.exe", is linked to Asus AI Suite. I will try uninstalling the Asus software and updating again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching the BSoD dump file, the associated file was part of **Asus AI Suite 3**. Uninstalling this and retrying the update worked.